# Loop through HashSet of Objects Java

Tags: java, object, for-loop, hashset

I am trying to loop through a HashSet of Enum Objects in Java 8 to see if a value is equal to a specific string. I have tried both `equals` and `==` but its not returning true.

HashSet looks like:

[image]

I have tried the following:

```
for(Object g : groups){
                if(g.equals("group_certification_staff")){
                    //Do stuff
                }
```

```
for(Object g : groups){
                if(g == "group_certification_staff"){
                    //Do stuff
                }
```

but it keeps returning false

What am I missing?

Comment: If `groups` contains `Enum` objects, then don't compare them to `String`s. Compare them to the `Enum` that you're looking for. Change `g == "group_certification_staff"` to `g == SecurityGroup.group_certification_staff`

Comment: Convert g to SecurityGroup and then compare.

Comment: Yes @mypetlion - you are correct

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason for using a String instead of `g.contains(SecurityGroup.group_certification_staff)`?

Comment: @VGR - no. I'm not use to working in Java - its honestly just lack of experience/knowledge with this. The statement given previous by mypetition was correct

Answer (score 0):

Strings do not equal enums.  You *could* write something like `g.name().equals("group_certification_staff")` to see if it has the same *name.*